# How to get backtrace without core file?

Tags: debugging, memory, linux-kernel

In case core-dump is not generated(due to any possible reason). And I want to know back trace (execution sequence of instructions). How Can I do that?

As /proc/pid/maps stores the memory map of a process.
Is there any file in linux which stores userspace or kernel space of a process?(May be I'm using wrong words to express)

I mean to say all address by address sequence of execution of instructions.

Comment: for a kernel code? Have you tried adding `dump_stack()`? http://www.stlinux.com/devel/debug/backtrace

Answer (score 3):

To see what the kernel stack for a process looks like at the present time:

`sudo cat /proc/PID/stack`

If you want to see the user stack for a process, and can get to it while it is still running (even if it is stuck waiting for a system call to return), run `gdb` and attach to it using its PID. Then use the `backtrace` command. This will be much more informative if the program was compiled with debug symbols.

Answer (score 2):

If you want backtrace to be printed in Linux kernel use `dump_stack()`

If you want backtrace to be printed in user-level C code, implement something like this

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <execinfo.h>
#define BACKTRACE_SIZ 64

void show_backtrace (void)
{
    void    *array[BACKTRACE_SIZ];
    size_t   size, i;
    char   **strings;

    size = backtrace(array, BACKTRACE_SIZ);
    strings = backtrace_symbols(array, size);

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%p : %s\n", array[i], strings[i]);
    }

    free(strings);  // malloced by backtrace_symbols
}
```

And then compile the code with `-funwind-tables` flag and link with `-rdynamic`

As told in http://www.stlinux.com/devel/debug/backtrace