# Printing Error line number, file, and registers in linux operating system?

Tags: linux, gcc, linux-kernel, x86, operating-system

We are building a linux like operating system from nothing in the most dreaded course at our school. We building it on the x86 processor IA32 architecture, and using PIC-8259. Anyway, we have finished setting up GDT, PIC, IDT, and Paging to a point that we are able to receive and print the 1st 19 exceptions in linux like below;

```
void divide_by_zero(void)
{
     printf("EXCEPTION 0:-you divided by zero");
     while(1){}   // will halt later
}
```

The exception function above just prints only the message, I want to extend it so that it prints out the file and line number in which the error occurred, just like what gcc does when you compile. I also want to print out the general purpose registers and flags if possible e.g edx, ecx, DS, SS, etc. I am stuck, I don't know how I could get/trace-back the line number and file one the program has reached the function above. We have too many files being compiled by makefile, and some errors like paging errors don't show up. If they do, they are just warnings

Comment: What happens when you write `printf("EXCEPTION 0:-you divided by zero, %s, %d", __file__, __line__);` or `printf("EXCEPTION 0:-you divided by zero, %s, %d", __FILE__, __LINE__);`

Comment: Can you try printing backtrace like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28874213/how-to-get-backtrace-without-core-file/28876255#28876255

Comment: @Milline, answer1 couldn't work because our os does have string.h or string.c

Comment: this is quite impossible, bcoz our OS doesn't have libraries like string.h, execinfo.h, and size_t in yr 2nd comment. The compiler gives error because it can't find them.

Comment: You might want to implement libraries with needed functions then :)